# NatTable - Percentage Sizing with Column hiding

Tags: java, nattable

I would like to use column percentage sizing to force the table to take on the width of the parent.

This does not work when I hide column(s) by default because the setColumnPercentageSizing() method does not seem to exclude hidden columns and does not correctly calculate the width.

Is there an easy way to adjust this in my code?

Example:

```
public void example(){
    createGlazedListsGridLayer();
    autoResizeColumns();
    nattable.configure();
}

public GlazedListsGridLayer createGlazedListsGridLayer(){
    SortedList<T> sortedList = new SortedList<>(eventList, null);
    this.bodyDataProvider = new ListDataProvider<>(sortedList, 
      columnPropertyAccessor);
    this.bodyDataLayer = new DataLayer(this.bodyDataProvider);
    ColumnHideShowLayer columnHideShowLayer = new
      ColumnHideShowLayer(bodyDataLayer);

    // In this example, hide the first column
    columnHideShowLayer.hideColumnPositions(Lists.newArrayList(0));
    this.bodyLayerStack = new DefaultBodyLayerStack(new 
      GlazedListsEventLayer<>(columnHideShowLayer, eventList));

    //...etc
}

protected void autoResizeColumns() {
    glazedListsGridLayer.getBodyDataLayer().setColumnPercentageSizing(true);
    nattable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration() {
        {
            cellPainter = new LineBorderDecorator(new TextPainter(false, 
              true, 5, true));
        }
    });
}
```

### UPDATE

It's not ideal but this is the closest I could get to it

```
public void adjustColumnWidth() {
    getBodyDataLayer().setColumnPercentageSizing(false);
    // Avoid the first column since it's hidden
    for (int x = 1; x <= numColumns; x++) {
        getBodyDataLayer().setColumnWidthByPosition(x,
                getParent().getSize().x / numColumns, true);
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2

Here are a couple of different things I tried in various combinations. None of them seem to keep the column hidden after a table is dynamically populated with data.

```
protected void enableAutoResizeColumns() {
    getBodyDataLayer().setColumnPercentageSizing(true);
    getBodyDataLayer().setDefaultColumnWidthByPosition(0, 0);
    getBodyDataLayer().setColumnWidthByPosition(0, 0);
    getBodyDataLayer().setColumnWidthPercentageByPosition(0, 0);
    getNatTable().addConfiguration(new 
       DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration() {
        {
            cellPainter = new LineBorderDecorator(new TextPainter
              (false, true, 5, true));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no solution for that. The reason for this is that the column widths are calculated in the DataLayer. The `ColumnHideShowLayer` sits on top of it and simply hides columns. It doesn't communicate back to the `DataLayer` that something is hidden.

In the end the `ColumnHideShowLayer` would need to re-trigger percentage size calculation based on the hidden state. But there is currently no API for that.

Feel free to create an enhancement ticket and provide a patch if you have an idea how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I had to do a workaround which is posted above. Not exactly ideal but it's close enough for now since that feature is not supported

Comment: The question is, do you need a static hiding of a column or should the user be able to hide and show columns. The later is not supported ATM. If you statically want to hide a column programmatically, why do you use the column hide/show feature and not simply set the width of the column to 0? You workaround has the drawback that on resizing the window the columns are not resized according to the parent composite size.

Comment: Static hiding with dynamic rows. If I explicitly set the desired column width to zero it works temporarily.  Once dynamic rows come in, the hidden column gets shown.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Why should the column width change once rows are displayed?

Comment: That's a good question :).  I have no clue why it's doing that. My guess is it internally recalculates the widths somehow

Comment: Please see Update 2 section to see if I've missed anything you may know of. I've tried those lines in various combinations to see if I could keep the column hidden but no luck

Comment: Have you tried to disable percentage sizing for the first column?

Comment: Yes but no luck. I tried 'setColumnPercentageSizing(true);' followed immediately by 'setColumnPercentageSizing(0,false);'

Comment: I have also tried manually setting the remaining columns in a loop calling setColumnPercentageSizing(otherColumnNumber, true);

Comment: You configure the TextPainter to automatically calculate the width. This of course overrides the manually set width. Some combinations of width size settings can't work. Either fixed size or calculated size.

Comment: Yep that's correct. When I remove the calculate boolean from the TextPainter constructor it works as expected